# How to detect images using transparency without using canvas?

Tags: javascript, react-native

My use case is that I need to change up my logic if the image is transparent. I also have to avoid using canvas.

Is there a way to detect if an image is transparent without using canvas?

Comment: Fetch the image using the Fetch API and analyze its bytes. If there is a pixel with an alpha less than 255, you have a "transparent image".

Comment: To be honest, I don't have a good idea, but i recommend you to use [OpenCv for Javascript](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/df0/tutorial_js_table_of_contents_imgproc.html) , it offers a lot and a lot of image processing operations and APIs. if you turn to their doc, maybe you will find something interesting :)

Comment: If you have only PNG files, libpng-js gives easy access to the pixels. https://github.com/flyover/libpng-js/tree/master/example